# Genelec 8030s vs Blue Sky Pro Desk - I can't decide!

Tags: monitoring

I'm investing in some new monitors for my home studio, and I just can't decide between a set of Genelecs or the Blue Skys...... does anyone have experience of these monitors, and which ones would they recommend getting? I've used Genelecs frequently, but after reading so many good reviews I'm leaning towards the Blue Skys at the moment, but would really like some input before I splash the cash!

Answer (score 7):

Might not be what you would like to hear but the best way to choose monitors would be to find a place to listen to them yourself. Obviously bring along some listening material that you're familiar with. That way, you'll only have yourself to blame if you don't like your purchase.

Comment: +1 on that one, plus it always takes some time until you're accustomed to new monitors... meaning, once you know how to judge your system, you can get stunning results on any (sufficiently hi-fi) speakers, IMHO...

Comment: Totally agree man; I've been working in all sorts of different edit suites recently and its crazy how much the monitors change your perspective of the sound. I'm used to the Genelecs hence them being in the mix, but I REALLY want to hear the blue skys as I've heard such good things about them!

Comment: And it is a completely personal thing. I've never like the Genny's, from day 1 that I heard them. On the other hand I LOVE my Blue Sky's. However, I know several folks, who are very good in the field, who prefer the Genelecs to the Blue Sky's. Like Hector said, have a good listen. If you're on good terms with your Music Retailer, they'll probably let you audition them in your studio for a day or two, to figure out which pair is for you, especially since you're ready to drop $ on them.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have that particular Blue Sky system at work (we've got the Big Blue 5.1 systems), but I can vouch for the quality of the monitors they build. I know they've also had some equipment THX certified in the past.

I've used Genelecs in the past as well (and we have a bunch of the 8030s in the video editing suites), and I can honestly say that I've never really trusted how well the audio you mix on them translates in another setting. I've found mixed results mixing with them when I take them to another system for listening comparisons (even other Genelecs, like in our screening room). That hasn't been an issue with the Blue Sky systems, and mixes that we've previously done on the Genelecs don't sound so great on the Blue Sky systems. The reverse is not true though, the mixes we do on the Blue Sky monitors have been great on most other systems.

I'll admit, this difference is also largely affected by the fact that we have much better mixing rooms now (acoustically speaking). Personally though, after years of weird experiences with Genelec speakers (not just in this job either), I would go with a Blue Sky system over them any day.

Comment: Thanks for this Shaun; you've kind of confirmed what my research has told me, and my gut feeling. I think the skys may be turning blue....

Comment: "I've found mixed results mixing with them" - so all is right then, because that is exactly what you want? :P (yes I know, sorry for this extremely lame joke. I can't help it)

Comment: @EMV LOL. I hadn't even noticed that pun. haha